# file_usage_add issue for compound field

Tags: 7, entities, files

I have created a custom compound field which contains a managed_file element in the field widget form.

The issue I am having is not with saving the file, but with adding the file usage information.

I picked [hook_field_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7) based on some research, but this is not working for new content or translating the node.

```
function MODULE_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
  switch($field['type']) {
    case 'FIELD_TYPE':
      foreach ($items as $delta => &$item) {

        // save file permenantly
        if ($item['IMAGE']) {
          $file = file_load($item['IMAGE']);
          $file->status = 1;
          file_save($file);
          file_usage_add($file, 'MODULE', 'FIELD_TYPE', $entity->nid);
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

The issue here is that when I save a newly created node, at this point, `$entity->nid` has not been defined. This number is required by `file_usage_add`.

Is there another hook that I can use to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm dealing with fields, `hook_node_insert` was overkill, but it got me on the right track.

The answer is to remove the `file_usage_add` logic from `hook_field_presave` and put it in [hook_field_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_insert/7) and [hook_field_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_update/7).

Remove from `hook_field_presave`:

```
function MODULE_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
  switch($field['type']) {
    case 'FIELD_TYPE':
      // no file logic here
      break;
  }
}
```

Add to `hook_field_insert`:

```
function MODULE_field_insert($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
  switch($field['type']) {
    case 'FIELD_TYPE':
      foreach ($items as $delta => &$item) {

        // save file permenantly
        if ($item['IMAGE']) {
          $file = file_load($item['IMAGE']);
          $file->status = 1;
          file_save($file);
          file_usage_add($file, 'MODULE', 'FIELD_TYPE', $entity->nid);
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Duplicate for `hook_field_update`:

```
function MODULE_field_update($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
  switch($field['type']) {
    case 'FIELD_TYPE':
      foreach ($items as $delta => &$item) {

        // save file permenantly
        if ($item['IMAGE']) {
          $file = file_load($item['IMAGE']);
          $file->status = 1;
          file_save($file);
          file_usage_add($file, 'MODULE', 'FIELD_TYPE', $entity->nid);
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the file usage by implementing hook_node_insert which gives you all node fields besides what you are looking for nid and the fid using file_load in that case you could add file usage